# The simplest JS for lazy load for images only? (no dependencies please)

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading

Looking for a simplest way for:
lazy load JS to load images only on a portfolio site.

Should be work on any browser, no jquery please, but simple pure js coding.
Have CSS class called ".image-box" where are the img.

Site is responsive but don't use different image source files for different responsive sizes.

Thanks for help me.

here the js code, i trying this but can't see a progressive image loading:

```js
function init() {
    var imgDefer = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

    for (var i = 0; i < imgDefer.length; i++) {
        if (imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
            imgDefer[i].setAttribute('src', imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
        }
    }
}
window.onload = init;
```

How can i use this on html?
Ok, load the script and then?

Comment: SO is not a "do my job for me" service...

Comment: @Buzz, and yet again _"simplest on your experiences"_ is very opinion based. So you still need to provide some relevant code.

Comment: Sorry, i'm green horn here. Code added.

Comment: If I downvote this question even further will I get a tech job?!?! PLEASE RESPOND sheesh

Answer (score 0):

Here's my custom lazy loader that I've been meaning to release as open source, but didn't get around to do so yet.

It's dependency free and only uses the regular DOM API.

It might not be perfect, but it should get you started. Please let me know if you need pointers on how to implement the missing imports.

```js
import {registerViewportChangeCallback, unregisterViewportChangeCallback,
  elementInView} from './viewportHandler';
import {querySelectorAllCached} from './index';

let lazyCache = {};
let lazyCacheList = [];
let imgElements = null;
let allLoaded = false;

function removeEventListeners (el) {
  el.removeEventListener('load', onLoad);
  el.removeEventListener('error', onError);
}

function onLoad (e) {
  e.target.classList.remove('akm-lazy-loading');
  e.target.classList.add('akm-lazy-loaded');
  removeEventListeners(e.target);
}

function onError (e) {
  e.target.classList.remove('akm-lazy-loading');
  e.target.classList.add('akm-lazy-error');
  removeEventListeners(e.target);
}

function updateImages () {
  if (allLoaded) {
    return;
  }

  if (!imgElements) {
    // Find all images on the page and sort them top to bottom
    // so that we can start preloading the topmost images first
    imgElements = querySelectorAllCached(
      'img[data-src], img[data-srcset]')
      .sort((a, b) => {
        const aTop = a.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        const bTop = b.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        if (aTop < bTop) {
          return -1;
        } else if (bTop > aTop) {
          return 1;
        }
        return 0;
      });
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < imgElements.length; i++) {
    if (lazyCache[i]) {
      continue;
    }

    const el = imgElements[i];
    if (!elementInView(el)) {
      continue;
    }

    loadImage(i);
  }
}

function loadImage (i) {
  const el = imgElements[i];
  lazyCache[i] = true;
  lazyCacheList = Object.keys(lazyCache);

  if (el.src.indexOf('mno_0643') !== -1) {
    // debugger;
  }

  el.addEventListener('load', onLoad);
  el.onLoad = onLoad;
  el.addEventListener('error', onError);
  el.onError = onError;
  el.classList.add('akm-lazy-loading');

  if (el.parentElement.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'picture') {
    for (const src of
      Array.from(el.parentElement.querySelectorAll('source'))) {
      if (src.dataset.srcset) {
        src.srcset = src.dataset.srcset;
        delete src.dataset.srcset;
      }
      if (src.dataset.src) {
        src.src = src.dataset.src;
        delete src.dataset.src;
      }
    }
  }
  if (el.dataset.srcset) {
    el.srcset = el.dataset.srcset;
    delete el.dataset.srcset;
  }
  if (el.dataset.src) {
    el.src = el.dataset.src;
    delete el.dataset.src;
  }

  if (lazyCacheList.length === imgElements.length) {
    onAllLoaded();
  }
}

function onAllLoaded () {
  allLoaded = true;
  unregisterViewportChangeCallback(updateImages);
}

export function initLazyload () {
  registerViewportChangeCallback(updateImages);
}
```

Comment: 1. Don't answer questions which show absolutely no effort..., 2. _"Should work on any browser"_, 3. `el.addEventListener('load', onLoad); el.onLoad = onLoad;` O.o, 4. this "answer" really needs some explanations...

Comment: Not too bothered about #1.

Comment: Regarding #2 yeah obviously this needs transpiling, so what?

Comment: #3 is for IE-compatibiity. It sure looks weird though, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

Is an [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) cheating?

```
window.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
  var images = document.querySelectorAll('#lazy-img');
  //if the browser doesn't support IO
  if (!('IntersectionObserver' in window)) {
    LoadImagesOldWay(images);
  } else {
    createObserver(images);
  }
}, false);

function createObserver(images) {
  var options = {
    //root defaults
    root: null,
    rootMargin: "0px",
    //threshold is how much of the element is intersected before firing callback
    threshold: .01
  };
  //create an observer, add the options and callback function
  //then add each image to the observer.
  var observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersect, options);
  images.forEach(function (image) {
    observer.observe(image);
  });

}
//load the smallest image for old browsers
function LoadImagesOldWay(images) {
  images.forEach(function (image) {
    var url = image.getAttribute('data-src');
    image.setAttribute('src', url);
  });
}

function handleIntersect(entries, observer) {
  // Loop through the entries
  entries.forEach(function (entry) {
    //if this entry is intersecting whatsoever
    if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
      var image = entry.target;
      //we get our responsive image set
      var url = image.getAttribute('data-src');
      //and set them as the actual source
      image.setAttribute('src', url);
      //we unobserve (Separate) the image entirely
      observer.unobserve(entry.target);
      console.log('lazy-image loaded!:simpleIO.js line 49 to remove this!');
    }
  });
}
```

I like IO because it is extremely robust and open-ended. You could lazy load *anything* with the intersection observer.

Check out an example with responsive images on my github

edit- wow missed all of the downvotes you got. Not sure why someone saw -1 and thought it need to be even worse. I thought it was a good question, just worded poorly. Don't let em get to you. :D

[Simple-Intersection-Observer](https://github.com/levyadams/simple-intersection-observer)